# Power consumption of a recirculating diode in a LED driver

Tags: diodes, power-electronics, led-driver

I have a LED driver design that is supposed to put out 10A at 5.2V and uses the [LM3409HV](https://www.ti.com/product/lm3409hv) driver chip from TI. I've been going through the design and I'm confused about how the power consumption of the recirculating diode is calculated. The datasheet calculates it as 750mV * the current through the diode (page 26, section 9.2.1.2.7). I'm assuming this is the diode's forward voltage. However, shouldn't this be Vin * the current through it?

Comment: No. Why would it? How does the diode know what the input voltage is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just look at it as a sort of voltage divider.

0.75 volt is over the diode, the rest of the voltage is over the other components.

Thus 0.75*10A of energy is consumed by the diode. The other (V-0.75)*10A of energy goes to the other parts of the circuit.

Hopefully most of it goes into your LEDs.